# conditional validation in the model of cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want condtional validaiton that while updating my password field is hidden and password validation is 'between 6 to 15' characters! so password is stored in hash format in database so it is not allow me to update. My model code is as below,

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Group',
        'City',
        'Area',
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'rule'     => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => true,
            'message'  => 'Only alphabets and numbers are allowed!'
        ),
        'email' => array(
            //~ 'rule1' => array(
                //~ 'rule' => 'isUnique',
                //~ 'message' => 'Email address already exists!',
                //~ 'last' => true
            //~ ),
            'rule2' => array(
                'rule' => 'email',
                'message' => 'Invalid Email!',
                'last' => true
            )
        ),
        //~ 'password' => array(
                //~ 'rule'    => array('between', 6, 15),
                //~ 'required' => true,
                //~ 'message' => 'Password must be of 6 to 15 characters'
        //~ ),
        //~ 'confirm_password' => array(
            //~ 'rule' => 'confirmPassword',
            //~ 'message' => 'Confirm password do not match!'
        //~ ),
        //~ 'address' => array(
            //~ 'allowEmpty' => false,
            //~ 'required' => true,
            //~ 'message'  => 'Description is required'
        //~ ),
        //~ 'phone_number' => array(
            //~ 'rule' => 'phone',
            //~ 'allowEmpty' => false,
            //~ 'required' => true,
            //~ 'message'  => 'Phone Number is required'
        //~ )
    );

    public function beforeSave() {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function confirmPassword() {
        debug('model');
        if ($this->data[$this->alias]['confirm_password'] != '') {
            debug('model in');
            if(strcmp($this->data[$this->alias]['password'], $this->data[$this->alias]['confirm_password']) == 0) {
                debug('model in in');
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

i also have confrim password validation. so tell me any solution for conditional validation! thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking for a validation rule to make sure the password is between 6 and 15 characters? Or something else?

Comment: you might also want to use field aliases for password as described here: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/ - makes your life a whole lot easier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have more than one validates array and select which one you want to use before you save:

in model:

```
public $validate = array(
   // default validation rules
);

public $validateWithPassword = array(
   // validation rules including password validation
);
```

Now, in your controller action you can select to validate with the password fields with:

```
$this->User->validate = $this->User->validateWithPassword;
```

Comment: There's actually an inbuilt mechanism for this now: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#dynamically-change-validation-rules, though personally I find handling `$validate` directly to be much easier to read. Still, worth mentioning.